# pass two promise from one service method angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

```
function getOrderItemInfo() {
    var deferred = $q.defer();

        $http.get('v1/order/show')
                    .success(function(res){

                      var data = res.data;
                      var users = auth.getCurrentUser().children;

            /*
              would like to pass deferred.resolve(data);
            */  

                        users.forEach(function(e){
                          e.user_id=e.user_id.toString();
                        })
                      var finalArray = _.differenceBy(users, data, "user_id");

            /*
              would like to pass deferred.resolve(finalArray); as well
            */  

                     if(finalArray.length > 0){
                          deferred.resolve(finalArray); 
                      }else{
                         users.status = "404";
                         deferred.resolve(users.status);
                         //return;
                         console.log("Does not exist");      
                      }

                    }).error(function(error){
                        console.log(error);
                        deferred.reject(data.message);
                      });

            return deferred.promise;
  }
```

I want to pass two promise from one function service
 deferred.resolve(data);
 deferred.resolve(finalArray);

When call this service method return two array is this possible please guide

Comment: You can resolve with an array: `deferred.resolve([data,finalArray]); ` Also in your error function data is out of scope

Comment: What if we want to combine both to one array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can create an object and resolve that object.

```
deferred.resolve({
   finalArray : finalArray,
   data :data
});
```

Comment: Like it as well